# Use rollapply() to get mean of specific/custom rows

Tags: r, rollapply

I am using `rollapply` (from the `zoo` package) in R to get rolling mean values for a series of rows in a data frame.

For each row, where the focal row is `x` I am trying to get a number of means. I can do this with a loop but it's slow, and I try to avoid loops.

The aim is to get rolling means for 4 different specifications:

1. mean of row `x`, `x-1`, and `x+1`: "Rat3"
2. mean of row `x` through row `x+7`: "RatE"
3. mean of row `x+8` through row `x+15`: "RatL"
4. mean of row `x` through row `x+15`: "RatJ"

Using loops I can get all of these, but its slow:

```
tempDF = data.frame(sample(c("A","B"), replace = T, size = 100),rnorm(100,10,2))
colnames(tempDF) = c("Cohort","Rat")

for(i in 1:length(tempDF$Cohort)){
       tempDF$Rat3[i] = (mean(tempDF$Rat[(i-1):(i+1 )], na.rm = FALSE)) 
       tempDF$RatE[i] = (mean(tempDF$Rat[(i+0):(i+7 )], na.rm = FALSE)) 
       tempDF$RatL[i] = (mean(tempDF$Rat[(i+8):(i+15)], na.rm = FALSE)) 
       tempDF$RatJ[i] = (mean(tempDF$Rat[(i+0):(i+15)], na.rm = FALSE)) 
}
```

I can get the Rat3 using the `rollapply` function:

```
tempDF$Rat3 = c(0,rollapply(tempDF$Rat, 3, FUN = mean, by = 1),0)
```

But I'm stuck in how to modify this to make it not centre around the value $x$, instead using $x$ (or $x+8$) as a starting point for the rolling average. How can I set the `rollapply` function to manipulate the way it "moves" the rolling average window?

Here's an inelegant solution:

```
tempDF$RatE = c(0,0,0,0,rollapply(tempDF$Rat, 8, FUN = mean, by = 1),0,0,0)
tempDF$RatE = c(tempDF$RatE[5:(length(tempDF$RatE)-3)],rep("0",times=7))
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck apologies - fixed

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `align` parameter, which can be set to `'center'`, `'left'` or `'right'`, but defaults to `'left'`.

As an aside, did you pre-allocate the four result vectors? That can often make loops slow.

Answer (score 0):

The two solutions in the question for `Rat3` are not the same.  `Rat3[1]` is `mean(Rat[1:2])` in the first `Rat3` solution (that uses the loop) and is `0` in the second `Rat3` solution (that uses `rollapply`). Assuming you want to zero fill (as in the second solution):

```
# roll is convenience function so we don't have to repeat some args 4 times
roll <- function(...) rollapply(FUN = mean, na.rm = FALSE, fill = 0, ...)
transform(tempDF,
            Rat3 = roll(Rat, 3),
            RatE = roll(Rat, 8, align = "left"),
            RatL = roll(Rat, list(8:15)),
            RatJ = roll(Rat, 16, align = "left")
)
```

This would also work:

```
transform(tempDF,
            Rat3 = roll(Rat, list(c(-1, 0, 1))),
            RatE = roll(Rat, list(0:7)),
            RatL = roll(Rat, list(8:15)),
            RatJ = roll(Rat, list(0:15))
)
```

See `?rollapply` for detailed information on the `rollapply` arguments.